# Display Sprite after Collision Detection Cocos2d 3.x

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

This is the code that controls what happens after the collision

```
 - (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair monsterCollision:(CCNode *)monster projectileCollision:(CCNode *)projectile {
[monster removeFromParent];
[projectile removeFromParent];
return YES;
```

Can i replace the "removeFromParent" with some sort of sprite display code that Cocos2d has

Thank you :D

Comment: Appearing what Sprite specifically ? Got more details about it ? Is it an attribute of the parent class ? Or it's the Node you're talking about ?

Comment: Im trying to display a sprite after a collision has been detected. When a collision has been detected the code removes the sprite "removeFromParent" so instead of removing it, it replaces it with a sprite

Answer (score 0):

Didn't quite got what you meant.. If you could make and Sprite Appear when collision happened? As this?

```
 (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair monsterCollision:(CCNode *)monster projectileCollision:(CCNode *)projectile {
//Creating another sprite on the position the monster one was. 
CCSprite *newSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"enemy.png"];
newSprite.position = monster.position;
[self addChild:newSprite];

//If you would wish to make it stand for a bit and then disappear..
CCActionDelay *delay = [CCActionDelay actionWithDuration:1.2f];
CCActionFadeOut *fade = [CCActionFadeOut actionWithDuration:2.0f];
[newSprite runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[delay,fade]]];

[monster removeFromParent];
[projectile removeFromParent];
return YES;
```

Comment: Exactly what i was talking about :D
How would I be able to put an animation as the sprite
My idea was an explosion (so 4 frame sprite) and then it disappears after a certain amount of time.

`CCActionDelay *delay = [CCActionDelay actionWithDuration:1.2f];` it would be a code like that for the delay right?

Comment: You would create a sequence of actions and at the end put a delay and after that delay action insert the fadeout or dissapearing action for your sprite.

Comment: Ive been trying and trying but i cant get it to be removed. 
Ive trying putting CCActionDelay but i dont understand how to use it